# React + Redux front end has trouble communicating with Rest back end

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, axios

GOAL:

I want to build a post section, where you can edit the post on site (no need to go to another link) and save it.

Here is the backend node:

```
//route: PATCH api/posts/:id
//note: edit post by id 
//access: private
router.patch('/:id', auth, [
    check('text', 'Text is required.').not().isEmpty()
], async (req, res)=> {
    const errors = validationResult(req)
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).json({errors: errors.array()})
    }
    try {
        let post = await Post.findById(req.params.id)

        if (!post) {
            return res.status(400).json({msg: 'Post not found'})
        }
        //check whether logged in user has right to the post
        if (post.user.toString() !== req.user.id) {
            return res.status(401).json({msg: 'User not authorized'})
        }
        //check text of the post and save
        post.text = req.body.text
        post.save()
        res.json(post)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message)
        if (error.kind === 'ObjectId'){
            return res.status(400).json({msg: 'Post not found'})
        }
        res.status(500).send('Server error')
    }
})
```

then I tested it with Postman, and it works fine. 
Then here is the Redux Action

```
//edit post by id 
export const editPost = (id, formData) => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }
    try {
        const res = await axios.patch(`/api/posts/${id}`, formData, config )
        dispatch({
            type: EDIT_POST,
            payload: res.data
        })
        dispatch(setAlert('Post Updated', 'success'))
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: POST_ERROR,
            payload: { msg: error.response.statusText, status: error.response.status }
        })
    }
}
```

And Reducers:

```
case EDIT_POST:
            return {
                ...state,
                posts: [payload, ...state.posts],
                loading: false
            }
```

Then the React front-end part:

```
import React, { useState, Fragment } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Moment from 'react-moment'

import Alert from '../layout/Alert'
import { addLike, removeLike, editPost, deletePost } from '../../actions/post'

const PostItem = ({
    auth, 
    addLike, 
    removeLike,
    editPost,
    deletePost,
    post : {
        _id,
        text, 
        name, 
        avatar,
        user,
        likes,
        comments,
        date
    },
    showActions, 

}) => {

    const [liked, toggleLiked ] = useState(false)

    const [editMode, toggleEditMode ] = useState(false)
    const [postContent, setPostContent ] = useState(text)

    const likeButton = () => {
        toggleLiked(!liked)
        if (!liked) {
            addLike(_id)
        } else {
            removeLike(_id)
        }
    }

    const editPostButton = () => {
        toggleEditMode(!editMode)
    }

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        editPost(_id, {postContent})
        // history.push('/api/posts')
    }

    return (
        <div className="post-item">
            <div className="post-item__bio">
                <img src={avatar} alt=""/>
                <h6>{name}</h6>
            </div>
            <div>
                { editMode ? (
                    <Fragment key={_id}>
                        <Alert />
                        <form className="form form--edit" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                            <textarea
                            name="text"
                            cols="30"
                            rows="5"
                            placeholder="Edit your post"
                            value={postContent}
                            onChange={e => setPostContent(e.target.value)}
                            required
                            ></textarea>
                            <input type="submit" className="btn" value="Done!" />
                        </form>
                    </Fragment>
                ):(<p>{postContent}</p>)}
                <div className="post-item__meta">
                    <p className="post-item__meta-item">
                        <Moment format="YYYY/MM/DD">{date}</Moment>
                    </p>
                    {showActions && <Fragment>
                        { likes.filter(like => like.user === auth.user._id).length > 0  ? (<div className={ "heart red" } onClick={()=> likeButton()} ></div>) : (<div className={ liked ? "heart is-active": "heart"} onClick={()=> likeButton()}></div>) }

                        <button type="button" onClick={()=> addLike(_id)} className="post-item__meta-item">
                            <span>{likes.length > 0 && (
                            <span className='comment-count'>{likes.length} &#x2665;</span>
                            )}</span>  
                        </button>

                        <Link to={`/echelon/posts/${_id}`} className="post-item__meta-item">
                            View {comments.length > 0 && (
                            <span className='comment-count'>{comments.length}</span>  
                            )} Comments 
                        </Link>
                        {!auth.loading && user === auth.user._id && (
                        <Fragment>
                            <button type="button" onClick={() => editPostButton()} className="post-item__meta-item">
                            Edit
                            </button> 
                            <button type="button" onClick={() => deletePost(_id)} className="post-item__meta-item delete">
                            &times;
                            </button> 
                        </Fragment>
                        )}
                    </Fragment>}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

PostItem.defaultProps ={
    showActions: true
}

PostItem.propTypes = {
    post: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    addLike: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    removeLike: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    editPost: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    deletePost: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    auth: state.auth
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addLike, removeLike, editPost, deletePost } )(PostItem)
```

PROBLEM:

after I push the submit button when in edit mode, I get PATCH 400 bad request with the post link. Every other buttons or links all works fine. Done (edit > done! through submit) is the only one that doesn't work.

I am fairly new to React and Redux and I am not sure which step has caused the problem. I'm guessing perhaps in this way we didn't find the id by req.params? Then how could I properly pass the id for updating then?

Comment: This might be a hit and miss but I noticed you are using a middleware on your backend `auth` and inside your `axios` configration, you are not sending a `token`. (if you are using token-based authentication).

Comment: Hi there, I did pass the auth, so the logged in user has the right to edit this post. It's just too long so I didn't include everything as this is the only part that doesn't work.

Comment: Post the full code so we can have a better look at what's happening.

Comment: @RohitKashyap Ok I have posted the whole part of the code.

Comment: Have you made sure that the id you are passing is actually being passed? Is the id undefined?

Comment: since other buttons works, so I would think the id of the post is passed correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have solved the problem myself now.

in React code: let's add

```
 const formData = {
        text: postContent
    }
const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        editPost(_id, formData)
        toggleEditMode(!editMode)
    }
```

withRouter and history is not necessary any more. The problem happened because I was confused with the state's naming. As we need to save data to post.text (as you can see in the backend), the formData must be {text: data}. In my original code, it showed up as {postContent: data}, that's why it didn't work.

Also in order for everything to stay up to date, we need to change the backend too, after we save the post, we need to find all the posts and re-render it.

```
post.text = req.body.text
await post.save()
const posts = await Post.find().sort({date: -1})
res.json(posts)
```

Then we also need to change the reducers:

```
case EDIT_POST:
     return {
         ...state,
         posts: payload,
         loading: false
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `onSubmit` looks odd to me. `editPost` creates an action / thunk, but that action does not get dispatched. Also `history.push` *should* navigate the page, so `/api` seems wrong there.

It might be that that also causes your bad request, but I am not sure about that because `history.push` is not standard a global function. It depends on its implementation.

Comment: I temporarily disabled `history` but still get the bad request. What do you mean by the action not get dispatched?

Comment: `editPost` creates a function that expects `dispatch` to be passed. That function is normally invoked by `redux-thunk` middleware when you dispatch it. But you do not call dispatch with your `editPost` action.

Comment: `history.push` won't cause a bad request error, that's absolutely ridiculous.

Comment: `history.push` could do anything really, because it is not defined. I also made clear that it *might* cause it. From the code specified its not even clear why the axios call is executed at all. So its not ridiculous to suspect the only other function in that callback to cause this.

Comment: could do anything? That's simply a bad argument. If it were undefined, it would say undefined. The request has clearly to do with the action, the actual request being made. Not history.push!

Comment: Oh you mean its caused by the action creator that is invoked, but which result is not even consumed, that's absolutely ridiculous.

Comment: Also I did not say its `undefined`. Its not defined in this SO post, so it could be *anything*. Not undefined. Ridiculous how you cannot understand that.

Comment: It literally says bad request, unless the endpoint is hit, the server will not send the response. That means it has something to do with how the request is being made. Not history.